# Assign approver to person specified for current item, in standard approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, approval-process

I would like a standard Approval process to a document library to be started automatically when a new item is checked in. The approver of the item should be the "Product Manager" and this info is provided with the current item.

So, I have copied a standard Approval workflow for SharePoint 2010 and the idea was to modify this. After modification in SharePoint Designer I am able to send a customized mail to the approver, using `[%Current Item:Product Manager%]`. But I suspect I also need to assign a task to this person, otherwise no approval will be done.

Where can I do this? I have looked both in "Change the behavior of a single task" and "Change the behavior of the overall task process", but this is far from self-explaining...

There is a `[%Task Process:Participant List%]` that looks interesting, but I do not know where to change that.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but your 2010 workflow is calling the "Start [Some approval task name] process on [Current Item] with [Some Variable]" step, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right! This is my first workflow. I have been looking everywhere for that "Start [Some approval task name] process ...". Now I have finally found it after restarting Designer, under "Edit workflow" - "Step 1"... I must have been somewhere else before because in this workflow the other customization options "Change behavior..." have disappeared.

Comment: In fact, you were in the 2010 approval subworkflow. This is where you can customize the steps & conditions of the approval. You access the subworkflow by clicking on the [Some approval task name] ("Approval" in the case of Kally_SPWX answer's image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, you want to assign task to the people in the People Column of the list item using SharePoint 2010 workflow.

It is not necessary to change the Email "To" to [%Current Item:Product Manager%] and assign a task to this person in "Change the behavior of a single task" and "Change the behavior of the overall task process".

You just need to change the approver of "Start Approval Process" action to [%Current Item:Product Manager%], like:
[image]

If the workflow is triggered, it will assign a task to the [%Current Item:Product Manager%], and send an email to him about this.